# Need clarification of creating resource in AWS API gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I couldn't get what actually a resource will help while creating an API gateway for a lambda function(python) in AWS

So, please let me know how can I use a resource in API gateway.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a resource in API-Gateway? For example how to create an endpoint to receive POSTs?

Comment: I went through AWS documentation about creating a resource in API gateway for a Lambda function, but I couldn't follow that in real time it will be good if got any real-time example for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Gateway handles the hosting and security/tokens (if desired). After the http request hits API Gateway it needs to be caught by a designated lambda. I'm assuming, giving your comment that you already have a lambda in mind. So for the *Build Lambda* step you can modify the code in `main` to be your code.

### Step 1: Build Lambda

To deploy your lambda you will need to create a Serverless Framework Service.

1) First install [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/)

2) Navigate to the directory where you want to store the API Gateway and Lambda files

3) In the command line run:

```
serverless create --template aws-python
# if you don't want to use python simply change the template language
```

4) Create a new file (in this example it's named lambdaGET.py) to be deployed inside your lambda

lambdaGET.py

```
import json





def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))


    event = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    # I recommend you verify the data here although it is not critical


    '''
    After the lambda has obtained the results it needs to correctly 
    format them to be passed across the API Gateway
    '''

   response = {
                "isBase64Encoded": False,
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers": {},
                "body": json.dumps(result)
        }



    return response
```

### Step 2: Build Serverless.yml

In this step you need to build the serverless file to deploy the lambda, API Gateway, and connect them together.

```
service: YourServiceName

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  timeout: 30
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-1'}
  profile: ${opt:profile, 'default'}
  apiName : ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
  environment:
    region: ${self:provider.region}
    stage: ${self:provider.stage}
  stackTags:
    Owner : YourName
    Project : YourProjectName
    Service : ${self:service}
    Team : YourTeamName
  stackPolicy: # This policy allows updates to all resources
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal: "*"
      Action: "Update:*"
      Resource: "*"

  iamRoleStatements:


functions:
  lambdaGET:
    handler: lambdaGET.main
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: /foobar
          resp: json
```

The events section of the serverless file is where you are declaring your API Gateway resources.

### Step 3: Deploy

1) Install [AWS commmand line](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html)

3) Set up your [AWS configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)

4) Make sure your directories are setup correctly: 
   (lambdaGET.py and servless.yml should be in the same folder)

````
```
-ServiceDirectory
 --- lambdaGET.py
 --- serverless.yml
```
````

5) Navigate to the ServiceDirectory folder and in the command line run:

```
sls deploy
```

### Step 4: Test

Your API can now be invoked using browsers or programs such as Postman

The base URL for all your services API endpoint can be found in console inside API Gateway > Service (in your case 'YourServerName') > Dashboard

[image]

Almost there... Now that you have the base URL you need to add the extension we placed on our endpoint: `/foobar`

Now you can place this entire URL in Postman and receive the output of your lambda.

:)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Of course, this will help me for my upcoming projects. Thank you @Kerri